# U2F instead of password for "sudo mode"?

Tags: authentication, u2f

Some apps (Github being the most prominent IMHO) allow using U2F token as a means of validation for "sudo mode" (potentially dangerous actions in UI like creating a new token) instead of password.

Intuitively it seems not very safe as a stolen device will most probably still contain the U2F token. Am I missing something that makes it safe enough?

Comment: U2F is typically used as a second factor. You still need the password to login. Mature sites probably have additional protection if the client changes “too much”, forcing a normal login before U2F can be used as a convenience.

Comment: I don't think I understand your point, David. You meant that U2F might be fine for some actions as convenience, but it's better to have normal password for critical actions?